# Suddenly cannot connect to university network, 16.04

Tags: wireless, internet

I have two university networks available at my work place (eduroam and the own's university net). Both have good signal strength and both use the same username and the same password to log in. I have always been connected to the university's network without problems.

Today I was connected for some time, then I could not access websites anymore though remained connected (according to the network symbol). When I turned Wi-Fi off and on again it would not connect me again, to none of the two networks. I tried with a Windows laptop and could not connect to either of those two for a minute or so also but now it works and the connection remains solid. I restarted the Ubuntu laptop after that and succesfully connected to the university's network again, then after a minute the connection dropped off again and will not reconnect.

Trying to reconnect now to eduroam it won't establish a connection and just asks me for my password again and again. Trying to connect to the university's network it tries for a while, shows a message (not able to connect) and won't try further.

Any help wih this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: just clarify that if any of device able to connect in your university network or not? and check that if your laptop is able to connect with any other wireless network(home network or personal hotspot)

Comment: I thought it was an error of connecting on two computers with the same username but now I'm connected with both laptops again. I restarted the network manager on Ubuntu and that seemed to have resolved things for now: 'sudo service network-manager restart'